# Rails Forem Bootstrap Theme not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, forem

I'm using these gems in a Rails4 project:

```
gem 'forem', :github => "radar/forem", :branch => "rails4"
gem 'forem-bootstrap', :github => "radar/forem-bootstrap"
```

I have this is my applications.js:

```
//= require forem
```

I have this in my application.css file:

```
 *= require forem-bootstrap
```

I have these files in my assets/stylesheets folder:

```
forums.css.scss
posts.css.scss
topics.css.scss
```

The forum works, but it's not Bootstrap looking.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

My app is using Bootstrap3 - is that part of the problem?

Comment: Don't forget to require the bootstrap js/css in your application.css/js files.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding this file to layouts:

```
forem.html.erb
```